# How does OCI/runc system path constraining work to prevent remounting such paths?

Tags: linux, docker, mount, procfs, runc

The background of my question is a set of test cases for my [Linux-kernel Namespaces discovery Go package lxkns](https://github.com/thediveo/lxkns) where I create a new child user namespace as well as a new child PID namespace inside a test container. I then need to remount /proc, otherwise I would see the wrong process information and cannot lookup the correct process-related information, such as the namespaces of the test process inside the new child user+PID namespaces (without resorting to guerilla tactics).

The test harness/test setup is essentially this and fails without `--privileged` (I'm simplifying to all caps and switching off seccomp and apparmor in order to cut through to the real meat):

```
docker run -it --rm --name closedboxx --cap-add ALL --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt apparmor=unconfined busybox unshare -Umpfr mount -t proc /proc proc
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
```

Of course, the path of least of least resistance as well as least beauty is to use `--privileged`, which will get the job done and as this is a throw-away test container (maybe there is beauty in the sheer lack of it).

Recently, I became aware of Docker's `--security-opt systempaths=unconfined`, which (afaik) translates into an empty [readonlyPaths](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/blob/master/config-linux.md#readonly-paths) in the resulting OCI/runc container spec. The following Docker run command succeeds as needed, it just returns silently in the example, so it was carried out correctly:

```
docker run -it --rm --name closedboxx --cap-add ALL --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt apparmor=unconfined --security-opt systempaths=unconfined busybox unshare -Umpfr mount -t proc /proc proc
```

In case of the failing setup, when running without `--privilege` and without `--security-opt systempaths=unconfined`, the mounts inside the child user and PID namespaces inside the container look as follows:

```
docker run -it --rm --name closedboxx --cap-add ALL --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt apparmor=unconfined busybox unshare -Umpfr cat /proc/1/mountinfo
693 678 0:46 / / rw,relatime - overlay overlay rw,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/AOY3ZSL2FQEO77CCDBKDOPEK7M:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/VNX7PING7ZLTIPXRDFSBMIOKKU,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/60e8ad10362e49b621d2f3d603845ee24bda62d6d77de96a37ea0001c8454546/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/60e8ad10362e49b621d2f3d603845ee24bda62d6d77de96a37ea0001c8454546/work,xino=off
694 693 0:50 / /proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - proc proc rw
695 694 0:50 /bus /proc/bus ro,relatime - proc proc rw
696 694 0:50 /fs /proc/fs ro,relatime - proc proc rw
697 694 0:50 /irq /proc/irq ro,relatime - proc proc rw
698 694 0:50 /sys /proc/sys ro,relatime - proc proc rw
699 694 0:50 /sysrq-trigger /proc/sysrq-trigger ro,relatime - proc proc rw
700 694 0:51 /null /proc/kcore rw,nosuid - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=65536k,mode=755
701 694 0:51 /null /proc/keys rw,nosuid - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=65536k,mode=755
702 694 0:51 /null /proc/latency_stats rw,nosuid - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=65536k,mode=755
703 694 0:51 /null /proc/timer_list rw,nosuid - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=65536k,mode=755
704 694 0:51 /null /proc/sched_debug rw,nosuid - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=65536k,mode=755
705 694 0:56 / /proc/scsi ro,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs ro
706 693 0:51 / /dev rw,nosuid - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=65536k,mode=755
707 706 0:52 / /dev/pts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime - devpts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666
708 706 0:49 / /dev/mqueue rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - mqueue mqueue rw
709 706 0:55 / /dev/shm rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - tmpfs shm rw,size=65536k
710 706 0:52 /0 /dev/console rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime - devpts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666
711 693 0:53 / /sys ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - sysfs sysfs ro
712 711 0:54 / /sys/fs/cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw,mode=755
713 712 0:28 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,xattr,name=systemd
714 712 0:31 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,cpuset
715 712 0:32 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,net_cls,net_prio
716 712 0:33 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/memory ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,memory
717 712 0:34 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,perf_event
718 712 0:35 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/devices ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,devices
719 712 0:36 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,blkio
720 712 0:37 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/pids ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,pids
721 712 0:38 / /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,rdma
722 712 0:39 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,freezer
723 712 0:40 /docker/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,cpu,cpuacct
724 711 0:57 / /sys/firmware ro,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs ro
725 693 8:2 /var/lib/docker/containers/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda2 rw,stripe=256
944 693 8:2 /var/lib/docker/containers/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0/hostname /etc/hostname rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda2 rw,stripe=256
1352 693 8:2 /var/lib/docker/containers/eebfacfdc6e0e34c4e62d9f162bdd7c04b232ba2d1f5327eaf7e00011d0235c0/hosts /etc/hosts rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda2 rw,stripe=256
```

1. what mechanism exactly is blocking the fresh mount of `procfs` on `/proc`?
2. what is preventing me from unmounting `/proc/kcore`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite some more digging turned up this [answer to "About mounting and unmounting inherited mounts inside a newly-created mount namespace"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517360) which points in the correct direction, but needs additional explanations (not least due to basing on a misleading paragraph about mount namespaces being hierarchical from man pages which Michael Kerrisk fixed some time ago).

Our starting point is when `runc` sets up the (test) container, for masking system paths especially in the container's future `/proc` tree, it creates a set of new mounts to either mask out individual files using `/dev/null` or subdirectories using `tmpfs`. This results in `procfs` being mounted on `/proc`, as well as further sub-mounts.

Now the test container starts and at some point a process unshares into a new user namespace. Please keep in mind that this new user namespace (again) belongs to the (real) root user with UID 0, as a default Docker installation won't enable running containers in new user namespaces.

Next, the test process also unshares into a new mount namespace, so this new mount namespace belongs to the newly created user namespace, but not to the initial user namespace. According to section "restrictions on mount namespaces" in [mount_namespaces(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html):

> If the new namespace and the namespace from which the mount point list was copied are owned by different user namespaces, then the new mount namespace is considered *less privileged*.

Please note that the criterion here is: the "donor" mount namespace and the new mount namespace have **different** user namespaces; it doesn't matter whether they have the same owner user (UID), or not.

The important clue now is:

> Mounts that come as a single unit from a more privileged mount namespace are locked together and may not be separated in a less privileged mount namespace. (The unshare(2) CLONE_NEWNS operation brings across all of the mounts from the original mount namespace as a single unit, and recursive mounts that propagate between mount namespaces propagate as a single unit.)

As it now is not possible anymore to separate the `/proc` mountpoint as well as the masking submounts, it's not possible to (re)mount `/proc` (question 1). In the same sense, it is impossible to unmount `/proc/kcore`, because that would allow unmasking (question 2).

Now, when deploying the test container using `--security-opt systempaths=unconfined` this results in a **single** `/proc` mount only, without any of the masking submounts. In consequence and according to the man page rules cited above, there is only a single mount which we are allowed to (re)mount, subject to the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability including also mounting (besides tons of other interesting functionality).

Please note that **it is possible to unmount masked `/proc/` paths inside the container while still in the original (=initial) user namespace** and when possessing (not surprisingly) `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`. The (b)lock only kicks in with a separate user namespace, hence some projects striving for deploying containers in their own new user namespaces (which unfortunately has effects not least on container networking).